# swift sprite kit moving between scenes

Tags: swift, syntax, sprite-kit

I have the following code to move from my main menu scene to the GameScene when a node is touched (set up as a button)

I keep getting crashes each time and have no idea what is causing it.

```
if node.name == "level1Button"
        {   level1Button.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square")
            level2Button.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square3")
            print ("level1button")
           // self.view?.presentScene(scene)

            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1.0)

            let nextScene = GameScene(size: scene!.size)
            nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill //set the scale mode like you did in your view controller

            scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)

        }
```

on this line I get

```
nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill //set the scale mode like you did in your view controller

//Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I am not sure how to correct this error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let nextScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

Comment: this only works if they have created a GameScene.sks file in the SceneEditor. You shouldn't assume they have.

Comment: actually I did have an GameScene ski and the solution above worked.

Comment: I also understand that its better not to have my variables in the gameScene.sks class but to put them inside the relevant functions inside the gameScene class, but I am yet to try that.

Comment: @carl I'm glad it worked for you, but it doesn't change the fact that the poster shouldn't assume which way you are presenting your scene. The comment wasn't for your benefit but rather the poster's so that they can properly phrase their answers in the future with more details of when to use it and under what circumstances, and why you should use this code vs the code you have.